# I cannot apply CSS properly to subtitles using :cue and more

Tags: html, css, webkit

I want to change and add custom fonts to my subtitles in chrome, so I figured why don't I use video:cue or something like that and it worked but to an extend ie the font size was way too large than before, text-shadow won't apply properly and more. Please help me. The image of the issue has been attached below and the code is also provided. BTW the reason I am using this is that the subtitles are embedded in the video, ie the subtitles are not in an HTML tag but are being burned into the video by chrome, this is not an issue in firefox as subtitles are not burnt. I am changing the subtitle fonts of Jellyfin to Netflix Sans and I want to share it with others in the skin that I made for it.

```
/*Fonts */
@font-face{
  font-family:'Netflix Sans';
  font-weight:100;
  src:url(https://assets.nflxext.com/ffe/siteui/fonts/netflix-sans/v3/NetflixSans_W_Th.woff2) format('woff2'),url(https://assets.nflxext.com/ffe/siteui/fonts/netflix-sans/v3/NetflixSans_W_Th.woff) format('woff')
}
@font-face{
  font-family:'Netflix Sans';
  font-weight:300;
  src:url(https://assets.nflxext.com/ffe/siteui/fonts/netflix-sans/v3/NetflixSans_W_Lt.woff2) format('woff2'),url(https://assets.nflxext.com/ffe/siteui/fonts/netflix-sans/v3/NetflixSans_W_Lt.woff) format('woff')
}
@font-face{
  font-family:'Netflix Sans';
  font-weight:400;
  src:url(https://assets.nflxext.com/ffe/siteui/fonts/netflix-sans/v3/NetflixSans_W_Rg.woff2) format('woff2'),url(https://assets.nflxext.com/ffe/siteui/fonts/netflix-sans/v3/NetflixSans_W_Rg.woff) format('woff')
}
@font-face{
  font-family:'Netflix Sans';
  font-weight:700;
  src:url(https://assets.nflxext.com/ffe/siteui/fonts/netflix-sans/v3/NetflixSans_W_Md.woff2) format('woff2'),url(https://assets.nflxext.com/ffe/siteui/fonts/netflix-sans/v3/NetflixSans_W_Md.woff) format('woff')
}
@font-face{
  font-family:'Netflix Sans';
  font-weight:800;
  src:url(https://assets.nflxext.com/ffe/siteui/fonts/netflix-sans/v3/NetflixSans_W_Bd.woff2) format('woff2'),url(https://assets.nflxext.com/ffe/siteui/fonts/netflix-sans/v3/NetflixSans_W_Bd.woff) format('woff')
}
@font-face{
  font-family:'Netflix Sans';
  font-weight:900;
  src:url(https://assets.nflxext.com/ffe/siteui/fonts/netflix-sans/v3/NetflixSans_W_Blk.woff2) format('woff2'),url(https://assets.nflxext.com/ffe/siteui/fonts/netflix-sans/v3/NetflixSans_W_Blk.woff) format('woff')
}
body, h1, h2, h3, h4 {
  font-family: 'Netflix Sans' !important;
}
video::-webkit-media-text-track-display {
  font-family: "Netflix Sans", sans-serif !important;
  font-weight: 700 !important;
  text-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 0em 0em .2em !important;
}
/*backup for subtitles*/
video::-webkit-media-text-track-container {
  font-family: "Netflix Sans", sans-serif !important;
  font-weight: 700 !important;
  text-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 0em 0em .2em !important;
}
video:cue {
  font-family: "Netflix Sans", sans-serif !important;
  font-weight: 700 !important;
  text-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 0em 0em .2em !important;
}
```

[image: subtitles]

Comment: Please provide more information. Are you trying to change Netflix subtitle fonts? With what? There are plenty of ready-made browser extensions, here's one: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/netflix-custom-subtitle/nncmiobjkolipmehdofkppnpcofggacm

Comment: I am changing the default subtitle fonts of jellyfin to Netflix sans using CSS as I am making CSS skins for it and sharing it with others, you can see the whole code on https://github.com/prayag17 ,  and I don't want to use a plugin for it

Comment: Maybe ::cue instead of :cue ? At least mdn says so: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::cue

Comment: Tried it but still didn't work